# Trying to replace pattern in data frame, but I'm getting wrong output possibly due to column classes

Tags: r

I have a data frame like the following, where columns 2 and 3 are factors.

```
radio <- data.frame(id = 1:6, snp1 = c("C/T", "C/T", "C/T", "Not aplif", "C/T", "Not amplf"), snp2 = c("A/G", "C/T", "A/G", "Not amplif", "C/T", "C/T"))
```

I wanna replace every "Not amplif" with "NOT AMPLIFIED", but notice that I have typos in this string, the only part always correct is the "Not". So I tried the following:

```
radio[ ,c(2,3)][grep("Not", radio[ ,c(2,3)], ignore.case = TRUE), ] <- "NOT AMPLIFIED"
```

But that gives me an error possibly because I'm dealing with factors. Then I tried to convert it to characters.

```
radio[ ,c(2,3)] = lapply(radio[ ,c(2,3)], as.character)
```

I tried the replacement step again, but now I replace the entire rows with "NOT AMPLIFIED", not only my target strings.

Please, help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting errors because `radio[ ,c(2,3)]` is still a data frame (you selected 2 columns), not a character vector. You can get the intended result a few ways, but this works

```
data.frame(lapply(radio, gsub, pattern = "[nN]ot.*$", replacement = "NOT AMPLIFIED"))
```

Split the data frame by its columns (as data frames are secretly also lists), use `gsub` to replace "Not and whatever after" with "NOT AMPLIFIED", then convert that back to a data frame.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks Adam! Don't understand why, but if I omit the argument names "pattern" and "replacement" I get the error "argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used", and these arguments are the first and second ones in the function gsub. But maybe the behavior is different when you call it inside lapply().

Comment: using the argument names is necessary with lapply or sapply because those functions basically take an object (in this case a data frame) and a function and *apply* to the data frame, using some subset of the object as an argument to the supplied function. In a lot of cases this works great w/o specifying other arguments, but `gsub` et al. have the "pattern" and such as their first arguments, so you have to specify them.

Comment: you can also write it with an anonymous function: `data.frame(lapply(radio, function(x) { gsub( "[nN]ot.*$", "NOT AMPLIFIED", x) }))`. In this case you're doing the same thing but you can see where the argument is being inserted. R is a bit funny because the order of arguments matters but **only** if you don't specify a name for the argument. So in the example w/ the anon fucntion above, we didn't have to name the args, because we ordered them. :)

Comment: To clarify on the need for the argument names:  When using a `*ply` style function, by default the things you are iterating over are used as the first argument to the function.  As Adam mentions, `grep`, `gsub`, generally have as their first argument the pattern to be searched for. Thus you need to specify the argument names.  Notice, btw, that the `stringr` family of functions actually have the `x` object as the first argument, making them a lot neater in `*ply` loops.